# Python - Calclulating angles of triangle with coordinates

Tags: python, geometry, coordinates, gis, mesh

I would like to create a 'triangle-mesh proofing skript', which would be able to find all angles in triangles, which are smaller than 10°.

The grafic example of the triangle mesh:

[image]

As my imput data i have list of element (triangles) with IDs of nodes which create them and nodes with their coordinates.

Elements [E3T element_id node_id node_id node_id]:

```
E3T 1540636 808597 808596 807843 1
E3T 1540637 808597 807843 807844 1
E3T 1540638 808597 807844 808598 1
E3T 1540639 807844 807845 808598 1
E3T 1540640 807845 807846 808598 1
E3T 1540641 808599 807846 807847 1
E3T 1540642 807846 808599 808598 1
```

And nodes [ND node_id x y z]

```
ND 778832 6.72399110e+005 5.33328776e+006 5.55937900e+002
ND 778833 6.72408176e+005 5.33328965e+006 5.55924300e+002
ND 778834 6.72404065e+005 5.33328561e+006 5.55974000e+002
ND 778835 6.72396071e+005 5.33329296e+006 5.56330400e+002
ND 778836 6.72394000e+005 5.33329700e+006 5.57010000e+002
ND 778837 6.72393587e+005 5.33329863e+006 5.57028500e+002
ND 778838 6.72409000e+005 5.33329600e+006 5.55550000e+002
ND 778839 6.72389548e+005 5.33329571e+006 5.56683100e+002
```

I would appreciate any suggestions for the quickest way to:

1. Find all elements with angles <10°
2. Find the node which creates the largest angle in the triangle.

Thank you.

Comment: You have no code so you're not likely to get any help here. This is a site for getting help with code. If you don't know how to solve this _without_ code, then you're asking this question prematurely. You have to know how to do this already in order to be able to code it. You have no [mre]. So it seems that you aren't even asking about programming, but instead, just geometry. Since this seems to be a pure geometry question, do you think https://math.stackexchange.com/ might be more likely to get you the info you need to be able to start programming this?

Comment: Of course, it's fine to ask here once you do know how to do this, as long as what you're stuck on has to do with programming and not geometry. We're here to help with programming, not geometry.

Comment: @RandomDavis Thank you for your comment.  I will edit the post with the description of the idea I have and try to write and add a piece of code in the evening.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate angle between two vectors?